# Pandas DataFrame cast to JSON supported data types

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I would like to understand if I can cast a **DataFrame** to **JSON** supported data types without having to *convert* each specific column directly.

I have the following DataFrame:

```
airbnb                                       date       revenue - sum   revenue - min   debit - sum
Premium Queen Ensuite                        2020-01-01 591.49          0.0             2
Queen Room w. Shared Facilities              2020-01-01 255.52          0.0             2
Single Room w. Shared Facilities             2020-01-01 1602.02         0.0             5
Compact Double Room w. Shared Facilities     2020-01-01 189.05          0.0             1
Premium Queen Ensuite                        2020-01-01 350.0           0.0             1
Queen Room w. Shared Facilities              2021-01-01 110.53          0.0             1
Single Room w. Shared Facilities             2020-01-01 4258.48         0.0             3
Queen Room w. Shared Facilities              2020-01-01 28.5            0.0             3
Single Room w. Shared Facilities             2022-01-01 578.55          0.0             2
Compact Double Room w. Shared Facilities     2020-01-01 4637.71         0.0             22

...
from decimal import Decimal
from pandas import Timestamp

pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'airbnb': {0: 'Premium Queen Ensuite ', 1: 'Queen Room w. Shared Facilities ', 2: 'Single Room w. Shared Facilities ', 3: 'Compact Double Room w. Shared Facilities ', 4: 'Premium Queen Ensuite ', 5: 'Queen Room w. Shared Facilities ', 6: 'Single Room w. Shared Facilities ', 7: 'Queen Room w. Shared Facilities ', 8: 'Single Room w. Shared Facilities ', 9: 'Compact Double Room w. Shared Facilities '}, 
 'date': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')},
 'revenue - sum': {0: 591.49, 1: 255.52, 2: 1602.02, 3: 189.05, 4: 350.0, 5: 110.53, 6: 4258.48, 7: 28.5, 8: 578.55, 9: 4637.71},
 'revenue - min': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0},
 'debit - sum': {0: Decimal('2'), 1: Decimal('2'), 2: Decimal('5'), 3: Decimal('1'), 4: Decimal('1'), 5: Decimal('1'), 6: Decimal('3'), 7: Decimal('3'), 8: Decimal('2'), 9: Decimal('22')}})
```

After reading the Dataframe I process some data *massaging* and *reshaping*.

```
df = df.set_index(['airbnb', 'date'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["revenue", "revenue", "debit"], ["sum", "min", "sum"]])
df = df.stack([0, 1])
```

Then, I convert it to a **dict** with some construction logic:

```
df = df.to_dict() # Possibly should use to_json
data = {}
for key, value in df.items():
    target = data.setdefault(key[0], {})
    for k in key[1:-1]:
        target = target.setdefault(k, {})
    target[key[-1]] = value

# data
{
'Premium Queen Ensuite ': {
    Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): {
        'debit': {'sum': Decimal('1')}, 
        'revenue': {'min': 0.0, 'sum': 350.0}
    }
},
'Queen Room w. Shared Facilities ': {
    Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): {
        'debit': {'sum': Decimal('3')},
        'revenue': {'min': 0.0, 'sum': 28.5}
    },
}
...
```

I have tried with [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). However, I get the following error:
`ValueError: Series index must be unique for orient='index'`.

The only solution I found so far is using [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). This works partially since the values (**Timestamp** and **Decimal**) aren't cast to JSON supported data types which is something I need (for an API JSON response):

```
{('Premium Queen Ensuite ', Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 'debit', 'sum'): Decimal('1'),
('Premium Queen Ensuite ', Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 'revenue', 'min'): 0.0,
...
```

This is the data structure I'm expecting to achieve:

```
# data
{
'Premium Queen Ensuite ': {
   '2020-01-01 00:00:00': {
        'debit': {'sum': 1}, 
        'revenue': {'min': 0.0, 'sum': 350.0}
    }
},
'Queen Room w. Shared Facilities ': {
    '2020-01-01 00:00:00': {
        'debit': {'sum': 3},
        'revenue': {'min': 0.0, 'sum': 28.5}
    },
}
...
```

Any way I can get around with this? Thanks!

Comment: How are you expecting your JSON to be? Since you have multi-index, you will get Tuples, which is not JSON compatible.

Comment: @Irfanuddin I have edited my question to include examples of what I have and what I expect to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have the bug is because you actually have duplicates:

```py
>>> df.assign(x=1).groupby(['airbnb', 'date'])['x'].count()
airbnb                                     date      
Compact Double Room w. Shared Facilities   2020-01-01    2
Premium Queen Ensuite                      2020-01-01    2
Queen Room w. Shared Facilities            2020-01-01    2
                                           2021-01-01    1
Single Room w. Shared Facilities           2020-01-01    2
                                           2022-01-01    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Take `Queen Room w. Shared Facilities` and `2020-01-01` as an example - you can't have this date twice in your `Queen Room w. Shared Facilities` sub-dictionary so there is no way you can really get a legitimate JSON for it.

Once you drop duplicates `.to_json` should work fine.